# Odd behavior in adding items to listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom photo gallery and I need to get the selected images and display their filenames in a listview

This is my custom gallery:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomPhotoGallery extends Activity {

    private GridView grdImages;
    private Button btnSelect;

    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private int ids[];
    private int count;
    String filename;

    /**
     * Overrides methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
        grdImages= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
        btnSelect= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        ids = new int[count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        grdImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imagecursor.close();


        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                int cnt = 0;
                String selectImages = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                        cnt++;
                        selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                    }
                }
                if (cnt == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    /**
     * Class method
     */

    /**
     * This method used to set bitmap.
     * @param iv represented ImageView
     * @param id represented id
     */

    private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                iv.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }.execute();
    }


    /**
     * List adapter
     * @author tasol
     */

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
                holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
                holder.chkImage = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.chkImage.setId(position);
            holder.imgThumb.setId(position);
            holder.chkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int id = holder.chkImage.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        holder.chkImage.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        holder.chkImage.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            try {
                setBitmap(holder.imgThumb, ids[position]);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            }
            holder.chkImage.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
            return convertView;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Inner class
     * @author tasol
     */
    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgThumb;
        CheckBox chkImage;
        int id;
    }

}
```

Now the result based on selection goes to main activity where I need to display all the selected images in a listview.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE){

            imagesPathList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] imagesPath = data.getStringExtra("data").split("\\|");
            try{
                lnrImages.removeAllViews();
            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i=0;i<imagesPath.length;i++){
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(imagesPath.length),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imagesPathList.add(imagesPath[i]);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,imagesPathList.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                yourbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesPath[i]);
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(yourbitmap);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                //lnrImages.addView(imageView);
                Uri uri = (Uri.fromFile(new File(imagesPath[i])));
                filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,filename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                encodedImage=  bitmapToBase64(yourbitmap);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,encodedImage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                myStringList.add(filename);
                myStringArray = myStringList.toArray();
                lv.setAdapter(null);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,(String)myStringArray[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        myStringList );
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Now my problem is:

1) If I select one single image it's showing me the toast with the filename but not adding it to the `listview`

2)If I select two images its adding to the list view as normal

3) If I select more than two its appending to the old list(ie..adding the newly selected images to the previously selected images) though I have set the `adapter` to `'NULL'`

4) Selecting large number of images takes time consumption to adding it to the listview `crashing` the app due to `memory`.

So can anyone suggest me the best way of handling this ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code. As in `Java` everything is reference, so instead of creating the adapter again and again, you should only set the new list to the adapter and then should call `notifyDataSetChanged`. For example, your `ImageAdapter` should be like this

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ArrayList<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();

        public void updateImagesList(ArrayList<Strinf> newImages) {
               if(newImages != null && newImages.size() > 0) {
                      this.imagesList.clear();
                      this.imagesList.addAll(newImages);
               }
       }
}
```

and then you should create global `Adapter` variable which we will be using for future list updates

and in your `onActivityResult`, you should populate the strings list in a loop and then after the loop you should update the adapter list as

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE) {
                for (int i = 0; i < imagesPath.length; i++) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(imagesPath.length),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    imagesPathList.add(imagesPath[i]);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,imagesPathList.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    yourbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesPath[i]);
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(yourbitmap);
                    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    //lnrImages.addView(imageView);
                    Uri uri = (Uri.fromFile(new File(imagesPath[i])));
                    filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,filename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    encodedImage = bitmapToBase64(yourbitmap);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,encodedImage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    myStringList.add(filename);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (String) myStringArray[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                arrayAdapter.updateImages(myStringList);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    }
```

Apart the above two changes, there is ***great performance impact*** because **you are all doing I/O operations on Ui Thread as you are decoding Bitmap files on Main thread** which is not the good approach as It will cause **OutOfMemoryError** as well as **It will slow down your application**. You should do bitmap operations or displaying using Universal Image Loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Hope this helps.